# How to make a nonhacky cursor in XNA?

Tags: c#, graphics, xna, cursor

I can currently get a button to show the click cursor in XNA:

```
    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        _spriteBatch.Begin();
        base.Draw(gameTime);

        if (_button.Contains(_mouse.CurrentState.Position))
        {
            _spriteBatch.Draw(ContentDictionaries.OneByOne, _hover.Rectangle, _hover.Colour);
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Hand; //<--- here
        }
        _spriteBatch.Draw(ContentDictionaries.OneByOne, _button.Rectangle, _button.Colour);
        _spriteBatch.DrawStringCenteredIn(ContentDictionaries.Fonts[Fonts.Miramonte24], _button.Rectangle, _str, _strCol);

        _spriteBatch.End();
    }
```

(DrawCenteredIn is just a helper method to help me draw in the middle of a Rect, nothing special).

The thing is it seems very hacky, the cursor somehow resets itself even though I don't reset it, and more importantly it comes from WinForms which (afaik) removes any sort of cross compat. and seems very hacky. Is there any way to do this in XNA?

Comment: _"which (afaik) removes any sort of cross compat"_ - well **mouse cursor** is **not** applicable for XNA on the **360** so there is that sadly.  _"The Mouse and MouseState objects are not supported on Xbox 360"_.  Anyway, why use WinForms?  Roll your own, it's not tricky

Comment: @MickyDuncan It's a TD game so it's not for XBOX. I was thinking more about Linux and stuff (through Mono) but I'm not sure if they support WinForms. IIRC they don't but that may have changed.

Comment: Looks like Mono does support WinForms 2. :) http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/winforms/